# Maven fat jar copies jarsignk.rsa/sf from dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar

When using the maven-assembly-plugin to create a fat jar including all the dependencies are properly copied to that jar. The problem is that one of these dependencies is apparently signed and contains a jarsign.rsa and jarsign.sf in META-INF. When I check the created fat jar, these files are now also in the META-INF folder. This causes the jar not to launch because the signature check fails.

I was thinking about some ways to avoid that, but couldnt come up with anything. There does not seem to be a way to include the dependencies as jars inside the jar. I was thinking also about creating a signature of the fat jar using the maven-jarsigner-plugin but this seems to be quite a hassle with setting up a keystore and whatnot just to override the one from the dependency.

So quick graphical summary:

```
-- t4sqlmx-3.5jar
   - META-INF
     - JARSIGNK.RSA
     - JARSIGNK.SF

-- app.fat.jar (has t4sqlmx as dependency)
   - META-INF
     - JARSIGNK.RSA (from t4sqlmx-3.5jar copied)
     - JARSIGNK.SF (also copied)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `maven-shade-plugin` I was able to add a a transformer like this:

```
<transformer
        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
    <resources>
        <resource>JARSIGNK.RSA</resource>
        <resource>JARSIGNK.SF</resource>
    </resources>
</transformer>
```

and now those files are ignored from the dependencies.